# Magento oAuth : Generating access token and access secret

Tags: magento2, oauth

I understand that the authentication endpoints include the following ones:

```
/oauth/initiate - this endpoint is used for retrieving the Request Token.
/oauth/authorize - this endpoint is used for user authorization (Customer).
/admin/oauth_authorize - this endpoint is used for user authorization (Admin).
/oauth/token - this endpoint is used for retrieving the Access Token.
```

I have written following python code to retrieve the magento access token and secret.

```
    class Magento_Oauth_Admin(restful.Resource):
        def get(self):
            return render_template('magentosetup.html')

        def post(self):
            consumer_key=request.form.get('consumer_key')
            consumer_secret=request.form.get('consumer_secret')
            magentourl='http://127.0.0.1/magento/admin/'

            session['magentourl']=magentourl
            callbackurl = api.url_for(Magento_Access_Token)
            temporary_credentials_request_url = '{magentourl}/oauth/initiate?{callbackurl}'.format(magentourl, urllib.urlencode(
                dict(oauth_callback=callbackurl)))
            admin_authorization_url = '{magentourl}/admin/oauth_authorize'.format(magentourl)
            oauth_session = OAuth1Session(consumer_key, client_secret=consumer_secret, callback_uri=callbackurl)
            # First step, fetch the request token.
            fetch_response = oauth_session.fetch_request_token(temporary_credentials_request_url)
            session['resource_owner_key'] = fetch_response.get('oauth_token')
            session['resource_owner_secret'] = fetch_response.get('oauth_token_secret')

            # Second step. Follow this link and authorize
            authorization_url = oauth_session.authorization_url(admin_authorization_url)
            return redirect(authorization_url)

class Magento_Access_Token(restful.Resource):
    """ The user has been redirected back from the provider to the registered
    callback URL. With this redirection comes an authorization code included
    in the redirect URL. We will use that to obtain an access token."""
    def get(self):
        access_token_request_url = '{magentourl}/oauth/token'.format(session['magentourl'])
        verifier = request.args.get('oauth_verifier')

        oauth = OAuth1Session(consumer_key,
                                  client_secret=consumer_secret,
                                  resource_owner_key=session['resource_owner_key'],
                                  resource_owner_secret=session['resource_owner_secret'],
                                  verifier=verifier)
        oauth_tokens = oauth.fetch_access_token(access_token_request_url)
        resource_owner_key = oauth_tokens.get('oauth_token')
        resource_owner_secret = oauth_tokens.get('oauth_token_secret')
        return render_template('magentosetupcomplete.html')


 api.add_resource(Magento_Oauth_Admin,"/v2/generateaccesstoken/",endpoint="generateaccesstoken")
 api.add_resource(Magento_Access_Token,"/v2/callback/",endpoint="callback
```

But at the first step itself when I am trying to generate the request token instead of getting the oauth token and secret I am getting the admin login page back.

Comment: is it because I am using Magento CE? is there a difference between Magento CE and EE in terms of REST oAuth Consumers registration?the UI is different for both

Comment: Base URL should be `http://127.0.0.1/magento`, not `http://127.0.0.1/magento/admin/oauth/initiate`

Comment: That was a typo on my part.. But I am working with the correct URLs in my code. Although I noticed that in your comment base url doesn't have admin at the end .. So I am using http://127.0.0.1/magento/admin .. I believe all oauth request go to magentohost/admin

Comment: Have you tried not to add `admin`?

Comment: Yes..I got a 404 not found if I use `http://127.0.0.1/magento/oauth/initiate`